# From domain www to no-www to subfolder

Tags: .htaccess, web

I want my domain without www always displayed, ie the URL is valid: http://miweb.net And besides this domain to point to a subdirectory and not the root directory.

How I can indicate in the htacess both conditions?

Comment: More specifics are needed please.  What subdirectory do you want to point to? Do all requests go there?  Does the user's address bar change to reflect it, or is it silently rewritten?

Comment: Your question isn't clear, what are you trying to do here?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at [`VirtualHost`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html).

Assuming you are using Apache, this will allow you to redirect URLs with `www` or other sub-domains to different folders on the server.

Comment: I have my website on Justhost (hosting), do not support virtual host and have the domain in godaddy.

I currently use the following htaccess:
`RewriteEngine on
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54 .php

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.myweb\.net$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/myweb\.net\/" [R=301,L]`

This is perfect. If you agree to www.myweb.net myweb.net redirects.

But I also want one more condition.
By default, my domain points to the server directory / www and I want to point to / www / myweb-folder /

How I can declare this in the htaccess keeping the previous property?

Comment: From what I know, this is not possible with `.htaccess` alone, because that is all about URLs, not server paths. Can you use PHP to redirect users based on something like `"http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";`?

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found the solution. Apparently it works:

```
    RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?myweb.net$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/myweb/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /myweb/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.myweb\.net$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/myweb\.net\/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ myweb/index.html [L]
```

1. If you access from a browser http://www.myweb.net, we automatically redirected to http://myweb.net (no www).
2. And that domain no longer points to the root directory of hosting "/ www /" if not "/ www / myweb /".